# Consecutive Difference Checker

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm writing a program that accepts a 2 or 3 or 4 digit number. The program checks the difference between each two consecutive digits of the number. If the difference between any two consecutive digits is the same, the program print True. Otherwise it will print False.
In addition, the difference between the last digit and the first digit of the number should also be checked.

Example1: 4840 returns **True** 
The difference between 4 and 8 is 4 
and the difference between 8 and 4 is 4 
and the difference between 4 and 0 is 4
and the difference between 4 and 0 is 4 (first and last digits)

Example2: 59 returns **True** 
The difference between 5 and 9 is 4
and difference between 9 and 5 is 4.

Example3: 131 returns **False** 
The difference between 1 and 3 is 2 
and difference between 3 and 1 is 2 
BUT the difference between 1 and 1 is 0.

Example4: 2420 returns **True** 
The difference between 2 and 4 is 2 
and the difference between 4 and 2 is 2 
and the difference between 2 and 0 is 2
and the difference between 2 and 0 is 2 (first and last digits)

Note that, I'm not using function, loops, if/else statements.

I tried the following code, but I realized it doesn't work for all option (2,3 or 4 digits), it works only if I knew how many digits before I run the program:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:   "))

ones = num % 10
tens = (num % 100) // 10
hundreds = (num % 1000) // 100
thousands = num // 1000


bool1 = thousands and abs(thousands - hundreds) == abs(hundreds - tens) == abs(tens - ones) == abs(thousands - ones)
bool2 = hundreds and abs(hundreds - tens) == abs(tens - ones) == abs(hundreds - ones)
bool3 = bool2 and tens and abs(tens - ones) == abs(tens - ones)

check = bool1 and bool2 and bool3

print(check)
```

So basically I'm trying to convert this code but without using if/else:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:   "))

if len(num) == 2:
    diff1 = abs(int(num[0]) - int(num[1]))
    diff2 = abs(int(num[1]) - int(num[0]))
    result = (diff1 == diff2)
elif len(num) == 3:
    diff1 = abs(int(num[0]) - int(num[1]))
    diff2 = abs(int(num[1]) - int(num[2]))
    diff3 = abs(int(num[2]) - int(num[0]))
    result = (diff1 == diff2 == diff3)
else:
    diff1 = abs(int(num[3]) - int(num[0]))
    diff2 = abs(int(num[3]) - int(num[2]))
    diff3 = abs(int(num[2]) - int(num[1]))
    diff4 = abs(int(num[1]) - int(num[0]))
    result = (diff1 == diff2 == diff3 == diff4)

print(result)
```

Comment: The result is always true for 2 digits and false for 3 digits.

Comment: for 2 digits right, but for 3 is not always, for example, the number: 555 returns True

Comment: Right you are! If the digits aren't all equal then 3 digits is false.

Comment: *input*, *int* and *abs* are all functions

Comment: *"Note that, I'm not using function, loops, if/else statements."*: Do you mean you would like to improve your code quality and use those, or are you asking for solutions that  shouldn't use those constructs? If the latter, then please edit your question and state this as a clear **requirement**.

Comment: What should be the boolean output if the user enters a value that is not numeric or out of range? False or True?

Answer (score 0):

> it works only if I knew how many digits before I run the program

You can count the number of digits like this:

```
size2 = 10 <= num < 100
size3 = 100 <= num < 1000
size4 = 1000 <= num < 10000
```

You also have a logical error in the evaluation of `check`. You don't need all cases to be true -- you need at least *one* case to be true.

You may observe that:

- Any two-digit number will comply with the rules. It is overkill to make the test `abs(tens - ones) == abs(tens - ones)` as you did in the expression for `bool4`. Obviously that is always true.
- With a 3-digit number the rules can only be satisfied if all three digits are the same: with a strictly increasing sequence of digits, the wrap-around difference can never be the same (because 10 is not a multiple of 3) and with an alternating (up/down) sequence the first and last digit will be the same, enforcing a difference of 0.
- The formula using `abs` calls is only needed when you have a 4 digit number.

So you can do like this:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:   "))

ones = num % 10
tens = (num % 100) // 10
hundreds = (num % 1000) // 100
thousands = num // 1000

size2 = 10 <= num < 100
size3 = 100 <= num < 1000
size4 = 1000 <= num < 10000

same_diffs3 = size3 and hundreds == tens == ones  # Simplified logic
same_diffs4 = size4 and abs(thousands - hundreds) == abs(hundreds - tens) == abs(tens - ones) == abs(thousands - ones)

check = size2 or same_diffs3 or same_diffs4  # use OR not AND

print(check)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python implementation. I use d for the distance between adjacent digits.

```
>>> def f(n):
...     s = str(n)
...     length = len(s)
...     d = abs(int(s[0]) - int(s[1]))
...     return length == 2 or (length == 3 and s[0] == s[1] == s[2]) or (length == 4 and abs(int(s[1]) - int(s[2])) == d and abs(int(s[2]) - int(s[3])) == d and abs(int(s[3]) - int(s[0])) == d)
... 
>>> f(4840)
True
>>> f(59)
True
>>> f(131)
False
>>> f(2420)
True
>>> f(2421)
False
```

Answer (score -2):

One concise approach:

```
n = input("Enter a number:   ")

result = len(set(abs(int(n[i])-int(n[(i+1)%len(n)])) for i in range(len(n)))) == 1
```

Create a set of all the neigbouring digits and check that it has size 1. You catch the first-last comparison by cycling back to the beginning with the modulo length trick.

Comment: Loops, function, if/else are not allowed.

Comment: @001 Not sure that is a real requirement. The OP just states that they are "not using function, loops, if/else statements", a statement that is not true for 2 of the 3 claims (they are using both functions and if/else).